# Ant setup for ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: deployment, ant

I have install latest version of ant from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/ant
and also i have done with setup as well.
but i don't get any package.xml file, so how can i do deployment in salesforce.

Comment: Did you also download and extract the ant-salesforce.jar file, and place it in ~/.ant/lib ?

Answer (score 1):

The metadata toolkit comes with a sample package.xml file. Copying the jar file doesn't automatically give you a package.xml file, nor is there a way to automatically generate one.

It's been a while since I've used Ubuntu, but it should go something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ant
cd
mkdir -p .ant/lib
cd Downloads
unzip salesforce.zip
cp lib/ant-salesforce.jar ~/.ant/lib/
```

At that point, create a new place for you to start working:

```
cd
mkdir workspace
cd workspace
```

There, create your build.xml, build.properties, and package.xml files (or copy them from ~/Downloads/samples, if you followed my code), and then start from there.

You'll really want to look at the sample files to see how to get started. They include information on how to do retrieves, listMetadata, deletes, and so on. Also, the [Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) home page has a link to the documentation that explains every available "task" (as Ant calls them), the parameters you can use, and so on.